# Deserialize a serialized object to map in java

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I want to deserialize a serialized object to map

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    // getters setters
}
```

I want to read this object in another application, but i don't have this class in classpath( and I can't control the serialization), so it will throws a ClassNotFoundException. But i want to know the fields information, like `name=hendrix, age=27`. How can I make this, is there a library do this?

Java serialize a object, it have to write the fields and value to the byte array, there must be an approach to deserialize it to a map, I wonder is there anybody already do this work for us...

Comment: Sounds like JSON to me.

Comment: Simply you can convert it to some other format like JSON or String or Map itself then serialize it and deserialize it in reverse.

Comment: Java Serialization doesn't allow you read an instance of a class you haven't loaded. You need to use a format which supports this.

Comment: @PeterLawrey OP could assume the object was serialized in the default, well-specified manner, and use the `DataInputStream` to manually parse and interpret the blob field by field.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik just about any other serialization this can be easily done, but Java Serialization makes assumptions about the existing of classes you are trying to deserialize.

Comment: @PeterLawrey That is understood; however OP is stuck with the serialized data he cannot control. Circumventing the regular mechanism is the only way. It's definitely doable, but tedious and brittle.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik you could parse the content yourself and even create the classes on the fly, generating code for each missing class based on the fields and their types in the serialised data. BTW Done this, but only once.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Here you wouldn't need to create the classes, just extract the data. A fully specific solution could just read out two fields at predetermined locations inside the blob and ignore everything else. Brittle, but could work if done against some stable data source.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik one problem is that Java Serialization tries not to repeat itself by using ids for classes/strings etc. Serialise one `Integer` and it takes 84 bytes, but the second one is just 10 more bytes. Also the size of the String might vary ;)

Answer (score 1):

Before you write it to a file, you could covert it to a Map and then serialize it.

```
public static Map<String, String> convertPersonToMap(Person person){
    Map<String, String> returnedMap = new HashMap<>();
    returnedMap.put("name", person.getName());
    returnedMap.put("age", Integer.toString(person.getAge()));
    return returnedMap;
}
```

And then serialize the Map object.  On the program reading the file in you can deserialize the file back into the Map Object.  This is due to the fact that Map implements `Serializable`

Comment: It's not me who do the serialization, they alreay write data using java serialization. so I can't using this method.

Comment: You omitted this key information from your question. In this case your options are very poor, you'd basically have to reimplement the Java deserialization mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the class file in your class path when deserializing the class.

If you want to transmit a class from one end of a stream to another, you could possibly push the `.class` file itself over the stream, save it to a file, and then use the ClassLoader :

Please See this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass%28java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29

Answer (score 1):

As already written in the comments, you can use JSON as programming language and system independent data format.

## Writing JSON

If your code runs in a Java EE environment, you can use the built-in Java API for JSON-Processing (JSR-353). Unfortunately it does support object-mapping, so you will have to do it by yourself:

```
// get Person to serialize
Person p = ...
// create intermediate JsonObject
JsonObject obj = Json.createObjectBuilder()
        .add("name", p.getName())
        .add("age", p.getAge())
        .build();
// write Json Object to Writer or OutputStream
Json.createWriter(outputStream).write(obj);
```

On the Java SE side, you can either download a library that implements JSR-353, e.g. the reference implementation at https://jsonp.java.net, or use any other JSON library.

For example, using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), the code above simplifies to:

```
// get Person to serialize
Person p = ...
// create ObjectMapper
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
// serialize Person to File, Writer or OutputStream
mapper.writeValue(file, p);
```

## Reading JSON

On the reading side, you have the same possibilities as mentioned above.

#### [JSON-P:](https://jsonp.java.net)

```
// create JsonReader from file InputStream
JsonReader r = Json.createReader(inputStream);
// parse JSON into intermediate JsonObject
JsonObject obj = r.readObject();
// get fields directly from JsonObject:
String name = obj.getString("name");
String age  = obj.getInt("age");
```

#### [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson):

```
// create ObjectMapper
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
// read file and parse JSON into java.util.Map
Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(file, Map.class);
// get fields from map
String name = (String)map.get("name");
int age  = (Integer)map.get("age");
```